# Tkinter - Adjusting widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm recently getting into Tkinter. Today I needed to create a scale, which has values snap to the left mouse button click. The standard seems to be, that it snaps to the right button.

Anyways, I found an answer:
[Force TkInter Scale slider to snap to mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817599/force-tkinter-scale-slider-to-snap-to-mouse)

**My question is:** Where can I find documentation of the "Scale" class, or any other class, so I can make such adjustments myself in the future?

I tried my best to contact the user who provided the answer and ask him instead. But the terrible and deliberate design choices of this site do not allow that.

Comment: I have tested the code on the liked post. It snaps to the mouse for me on both left and right clicks. That said you can contact a user by using the @ sign. IE `@Leviathan` in a comment or simply commenting on their post would alert them there is a new message.

Comment: If you are not able to contact the user of that answer this site is doing the its job correctly! You can leave a comment with a specific/detailed question ("where are the docs for Tk Scale or xxx functionality/property ?"). That user will reply if they want/can. Google "Tkinter scale doc" or "Python Tkinter slider". You will find the Tcl/Tk and Python documentation. By experience I found that usually other website with code example and explanations are more useful but to know all the options the official documentation is the right place. https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/scale.htm

Comment: @Alex75 Thanks that is the answer i was looking for.

Didn't find it when i googled "tkinter scale documentation". But maybe i'm blind.

Yes, the site is doing it's job "correctly", that's why i added the word "deliberate". It's horrible. I don't want to spam the site for such things.

Comment: In case you want to google the rest, `tcl/tk documentation` is the keyword.

Comment: @HenryYik Yupp, thanks.